# Xcode DEBUG Mode - when is it on/off?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

I have noticed that this works in dev mode (testing on the simulator, etc):

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    //do stuff
#endif
```

But when I archive and distribute test builds, the app does not act in DEBUG mode even though I'm still building with the developer profile. I would like DEBUG mode to always be the case unless I build with the deployment profile and submit to Apple.

For example, when sending test builds out, I don't want to make people buy an in-app purchase, so I do something like this:

```
- (BOOL)isUpgradePurchased
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    return YES;
#endif

//do the real stuff to determine if purchased and return YES or NO
}
```

So do I also need to set a preprocessor macro DEBUG=1 for "Release"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[image]

You can also "Edit Scheme" to build Debug Configuration when archiving. See screenshot of "Edit Scheme" dialog in XCode.

Comment: So I should be able to just change "Release" to "Debug" in the Archive Build Configuration right?

Comment: yes, but you have to change it to release before submitting to Apple.

Comment: I have a different scheme altogether for AppStore.

Comment: Hello @msk If I change only RUN mode in Build Configuration "release", then what should I change before submitting to APPLE ?

Answer (score 16):

The current version of Xcode automatically sets the `DEBUG` macro in new projects. It does this only for Debug build mode however.

You can edit this in your projects Build Settings.

I recommend you add a new, separate macro instead of editing the DEBUG one. Maybe you could add a `DISTRIBUTION` or `DEPLOYMENT` macro only for the release mode.

[image]

Comment: But can't I also just say DEBUG=1 for Release Mode?

Comment: You can. But that kind of defeats its purpose.