# Debugg iOS Cordova app

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

I have built an iOS app with Cordova and I'm trying to debug it with my Mac. I have followed [this tutorial](http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/debugging-ios-phonegap-apps-with-safaris-web-inspector.html), but when I go to `Develop -> iPhone xxx` there is no apps able to be debugged.

I have built the app using Intel XDK tool. Is there a way to enable debugging in my iOS app?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I have tried to debug my app with [GapDebug](https://www.genuitec.com/products/gapdebug/) but it doesn't recognize my app as debuggable.

I have created my app with a production/distribution certificate, not with development one. Maybe, can it be the reason why I can't debug my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every Application you create with cordova is compiled with an activated Debugmode. If it is not, you're able to change this via https://stackoverflow.com/a/12499274/3671726

Instead of debugging your Application with Safari, i would recommend you to install Google Chrome and [GapDebug](https://www.genuitec.com/products/gapdebug/) in combination. Go on that website, check out that video - you'll love that tool. Is very impressive, how and how smart gapDebug handles your debugging.

**Solved**

Like he found out on himself, he compiled the application with the wrong certificate. So be sure to use a **provisioning profile which includes a development certificate** and not a distribution certificate.

Comment: Thanks. GapDebug is not able to debug my app. I have edited my question.

Comment: Could be the problem, change your Certificate / Profile in XCode to a development Certificate and try out.

Answer (score 2):

I was using a distribution/production certificate to sign my app, so I couldn't debug it. I have created a new provisioning profile with a development certificate and now it is working like a charm.

I'm using GapDebug like said Sithys. It is a good tool, thanks.

Comment: Was there no way around using XCode? I love the Intel XDK tool, but it can only build for distribution... what a shame!