# iOS 10 how to check if the app is downloaded from AppStore or from Xcode in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode8, ios10

I want to check if the App is downloaded from AppStore or from Xcode(debug mode). in iOS9 or below my code is working fine but in iOS10 it is not supporting.My Code is as follows.

```
BOOL isAppFromAppStore;
      if ([NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSBundle mainBundle].appStoreReceiptURL] != nil) {
            isAppFromAppStore = YES;
        } else {
            isAppFromAppStore = NO;
        }
    if (isAppFromAppStore) {
    NSLog(@"App is downloaded from AppStore");
    } else {
    NSLog(@"App is in Debug mode");
    }
```

Can Any body help me to solve this issue my code is working fine for iOS9 or below but not on iOS10.

Comment: Xcode by default supplies a `DEBUG` macro that you can use to check if you're currently in a debug or release build. Assuming you work locally using debug builds and are submitting a release build to the app store, you should be able to check `if (DEBUG) {...}`; is this sufficient for your needs? (See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12499001/xcode-debug-mode-when-is-it-on-off)

Answer (score 0):

Add a #define to GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS in your build settings or xcconfig, with a different value for app store builds and local builds.